# Keychain Access app opens on login Big Sur. Did not set as login item

Tags: keychain, big-sur, login-items

For the past day, Keychain Access has been opening on login on my M1 MacBook Air running Big Sur 11.3. Did not set it as a login item.

What could be the cause and what should I do to check for any security issues that caused or could result from this? No one else uses this machine but me.

Answer (score 1):

When you have log in and see Keychain running, try right-clicking its icon in the dock. Under "Options", you'll find "Open at Login" - make sure it is not checked.

Then right-click the dock icon again and select "Quit" to ensure that the application is fully closed.

Now you can log out and login again, and hopefully Keychain Access won't start up automatically.